# sys/queue.h: Use of LIST_REMOVE

Tags: c, list, pointers

I'm trying to use the `sys/queue.h` file from OpenBSD to manipulate a linked list.

I am writing a cache engine for a small microcontroller. Pages are stored in the cache when used, and removed when the memory is needed for other things like malloc.

This task needs to find the minimum hit count cache page (the one with the least number of hits is the least likely to be used) and free it. However, I'm hitting upon a fairly simple error.

This is my function so far:

```
void _fmem_cache_malloc_purge(int requested_size)
{
    int n = ((requested_size / FMEM_SECTOR_SIZE) + 1) * FMEM_SECTOR_SIZE;
    struct s_fmem_cache_entry *entry, *lowentry;
    long int lowhits;   
    fmem_acquire();
    for(; n > 0; n--)
    {
        // Traverse the cache table. Find an entry with a minimum number of hits.
        lowhits = -1;
        LIST_FOREACH(entry, &fmem_cache, entry_ptr)
        {
            if(lowhits == -1 || lowhits > entry->hits)
            {
                lowentry = entry;
                lowhits = entry->hits;
            }
        }
        // Free the minimum entry.
        assert(lowhits > 0);
        LIST_REMOVE(lowentry, entry_ptr);    <-- error occurs here (line 170)
        mmgr_free(lowentry->data);
        mmgr_free(lowentry);
        fmem_cache_size--;
    }
    fmem_release();
}
```

Definitions (near the top of the same file):

```
struct s_fmem_cache_entry {
        fAddr addr;
        char data[FMEM_SECTOR_SIZE];
        long int hits, ctime;
        LIST_ENTRY(fmem_cache_entry) entry_ptr;
    };

LIST_HEAD(s_fmem_cache_head, s_fmem_cache_entry) fmem_cache;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
flashmem.c: In function '_fmem_cache_malloc_purge':
flashmem.c:160: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
flashmem.c:170: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

I feel like it's a simple error, but C is new to me.

Comment: When you see a "incomplete type" warning,  you know you missed a #include file.  If you want to know which one.... you have to show the line number.

Comment: @J-16 @Eregrith `<-- error occurs here` marks line 170. `LIST_FOREACH(entry, &fmem_cache, entry_ptr)` is line 160.

Comment: Please put definitions of `fmem_cache` and `entry_ptr`. If `lowentry` is not initialized inside the foreach loop, it points to junk memory location and `LIST_REMOVE` could fail.

Comment: @user718895 I've added the definitions. Thanks for the warming about `lowentry`; I'll add a test for this.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the `struct s_fmem_cache_entry` definition at `LIST_ENTRY(fmem_cache_entry) entry_ptr`

From queue.h we can see that

```
#define LIST_ENTRY(type)                                                \
struct {                                                                \
         struct type *le_next;   /* next element */                      \
         struct type **le_prev;  /* address of previous next element */  \
}
```

so when you use `LIST_ENTRY` it basically becomes a nameless struct like below. This is why the compiler is giving the error.

```
struct {
    struct fmem_cache_entry *le_next;
    struct fmem_cache_entry **le_prev;
} entry_ptr;
```

You can easily avoid this by not using the `LIST_ENTRY` and by declaring the `struct entry_ptr` yourself. I am not sure of any alternative solutions to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
LIST_ENTRY(fmem_cache_entry) entry_ptr;
```

should be

```
LIST_ENTRY(s_fmem_cache_entry) entry_ptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the types you use with `LIST_FOREACH` (I guess this is line 160) and `LIST_REMOVE` (10 lines later, so it must be 170).
The definitions of `fmem_cache` and `entry_ptr` are not in your post, so I can't say what the error is.

I suggest you carefully read the documentation of the list macros you used, and check that the types of everything you use with them is correct.

It also seems like `struct s_fmem_cache_entry` isn't defined in your code (or the header where it's defined isn't included).